# How to change the invoice price manually? is it possible or not?

Tags: magento, invoice

Magento generated Invoice for Order. Client was asking change the invoice price in manually is possible or not?

Comment: Invoice Totals or Order Totals?

Comment: How can i edit the invoice amount  after invoice is generated or Is there any other chance to variations in the amount.

Answer (score 1):

Try following,
your module's `config.xml`

```
<sales_order_invoice_save_after>
    <observers>
        <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>invoiceSaveAfter</method>
        </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
    </observers>
</sales_order_invoice_save_after>
```

Your `Observer.php`

```
public function invoiceSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        if ($invoice->getBaseDonateAmount()) {
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            //Do your stuff here
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

More [information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11603/2206)